# three column fluid layout with twitter bootstrap - clearfixes messing things up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create a three column layout with a fluid center and fixed sides. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vPqA/12/). It seems as though the clearfixes for the nav is pushing the main content below the sidebars. Without the clearfixes, the content in general begins to be displayed incorrectly. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `.nav-tabs` div as `inline-block` to contain it within its boundaries properly, like so:

```
.nav-tabs {
 display: inline-block;
 width:100%;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6vPqA/15/show/
edit: http://jsfiddle.net/6vPqA/15/

edit: added width so the menu will adapt better.

Comment: Excellent answer. Bear in mind that instead of declaring your own "left" and "right" classes you can use bootstraps "pull-left" and "pull-right"

Comment: @JonathanOng because block level elements dont contain themselves within their boundaries unless an specific width and height is specified. Otherwise they just stretch as far as their container permits them. `display:inline-block` allows for the element to keep within its boundaries and margins so it doesn't fill up that empty space which you saw before the fix was applied.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a height for the nav class seems to pull the content up between the sidebars.

Something like:

```
.nav {height:50px}
```